# How to debug or run in embed window in Visual Studio？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I am running my project, there is a terminal open in another window. I want like Jetbrains or VS Code, the window is embedded in the editor.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio supports that functionality yet - VS only added support for Terminal/Shell windows [about two years ago](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/) and it doesn't support running/debugging programs attached to that terminal (or stdin/stdout/stderr).